# Cross-platform parallel applications with assembler inserts

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, assembly

I'm working on my coursework and there's issue about cross-platform parallel applications with inline assembler, so could you help me with some information?
What I found is there we have Intel and AT&T(gas) syntax of assembler and it all depends of it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of information do you want?

Comment: I want to know about a problem that further the programmer would run into,... and in general I need to reveal this topic

Comment: @gixdev, that's pretty vague.  Please try asking a specific question.

Comment: @gixdev - for the record, you cannot use assembler inserts in Java.  For a Java application, you'd have to put the inserts into C/C++ code, and call that code using JNI / JNA.

Comment: What is an "assembler insert"?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing. By that I mean inline assembler

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, the task is about creating cross-platform applications in C++ with inline assembler inserts. And because MSVC and GCC use different inline assembler syntax the question is how to practically do it.
In general, there are 2 options and they both are quite simple:

1) If you use MSVC on Windows and GCC on other platforms then just put assembler inserts in conditional groups:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
__asm {
    mov eax, ebx
}
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
__asm__ ("movl %ebx, %eax");
#else
#error Unknown compiler
#endif
```

2) Inline inserts may look clumsy if you have to put more-less complex logic in them, so instead you may want to move assembler code into separate .asm (for MSVC) or .s (for GCC) files and use it as extern function(s).

First, you need to define an external function in C++ (perhaps in a header):

```
extern "C" void some_func();
```

Then the things differ a bit for GCC and MSVC.
For GCC you will need to add a single .s file to your build:

```
    .text

    // function declaration
    .global some_func

    // copies ebx to eax
    .type some_func, @function

some_func:
    movl %ebx, %eax
    ret
```

For MSVC you will need 2 files. One is some sort of a header (.inc)

```
some_func PROTO
```

And another one is your .asm file

```
    INCLUDE some_func.inc
    .data

    .code

some_func PROC
    OPTION PROLOGUE:NONE, EPILOGUE:NONE

    mov eax, ebx
    ret

some_func endp

end
```

Obviously you will need to tell your build system that with MSVC toolset it should compile the .asm and with GCC it should compile the .s.

If you need to pass parameters to assembler functions you will have to understand the calling conventions for the target platforms. For MSVC they are following: [x86](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx) and [x86-64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b372w95.aspx). GCC seems like it adheres to Application Binary Interfaces of concrete architectures.